# i want to add increment of 6% to the return result from the query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<td>
    <strong>
        Rs @(Model.lstItem.Sum(c => c._product.option != null
                ? (c._product.option.Price * c.Quantity)
                : (c._product.product.Price * c.Quantity))
            - (Model.coupon != null ? (int)Model.coupon.Discount : 0))
    </strong>
</td>
```

first of all let me tell you i am totally new in asp.net mvc..
Now my question is i have the above query which is returning total after multiplying price and quantity. now what i want is i want to increment 6% of price*quantity to the price*quanity..

The final result will be like (price * quantity) + 6% of price * quanity..

i hope you guys understand my question

Comment: Simple math.  `1.06 * price * quantity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't keep these `constants` in the `View`. If you have these calculations in multiple places and you wanted to change the percentage to 7% in the future, you'd have to change everywhere. So, it should either come from your database, or a config file or a constants class.

So, the easiest way to do this is to create a static class called `ApplicationConstants` in a `Common` folder or `Utility` folder.

```
public static class ApplicationConstants
{
     public const int ProfitPercentage = 6;
}
```

Then in your `View`,

```
@using YourAppName.Common

<td>
    <strong>
        Rs @( 
             (1 + ApplicationConstants.ProfitPercentage / 100) *
             (Model.lstItem.Sum(c => c._product.option != null
                ? (c._product.option.Price * c.Quantity)
                : (c._product.product.Price * c.Quantity)))
            - (Model.coupon != null ? (int)Model.coupon.Discount : 0))
    </strong>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
(price * quantity) + (((price * quantity)/100) * 6))
```